# Two columns flex-box layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need create layout which will contain list of items in two columns. Like i showed below:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

But there is a problem with such layout. If there will be only 1 item - it will take full width. And i need to keep columns even if there are a few items.

Comment: Use flex-basis: 50% for the childs. flex-direction: row; and flex-wrap: wrap; on parent.
Also a very helpful guide to get started: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set a max-width for the item, equal to 50%. This will keep it, almost, the same width no matter what. I say almost because you also have borders set.

In order to keep the width exactly the same, you also have to set box-sizing: border-box for item.

So, your code will be:

```
.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can we limit it to two columns only so it won't extend horizontally? Like so https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuPArlo

Comment: Google tells me that this answer is 1641 days old. I didn't ask for that kind of specificity, but I kind of dig it. This answer just salvaged my grade in Website Development in 2021

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use the following code below:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `fixed two columns` without changing on dependencies (like device responsive), you don't need to use `Flex`

try this one on child element's

```css
.childs {
display: inline-block;
max-width:50%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Major drawback of this approach: text from the second column will overflow into the first one.