# How to change header position in dropdown (dropdown-content) menu?

Tags: html, css

that's my first project and wanted to know ho to change the header position in a dropdown menu like is on that site https://www.developerfusion.com/t/csharp/forum/. When you move the cursor over .NET you can see that 'technologies' and 'languages' are on the left side in that menu while 'latest news' is on the right side. I'm trying to do the same but don't know and couldn't find info how to move the header to to the upper right corner. Thanks for your help

thats is a piece of my code:

```
    .dropbtn {
        color: steelblue;
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-right: thin;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;

    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 420px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 56px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: cornflowerblue;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
     }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: steelblue;
        color: white;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: midnightblue;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href=".net" class="dropbtn">.NET</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <h5>Languages</h5>
                    <a href="csharp">C#</a>
                    <a href="vb.net">VB.NET</a>
                    <a href="fsharp">F#</a>
                    <h5>Technologies</h5>
                    <a href="azure">Azure</a>                       
                    <a href="asp.net">ASP.NET</a>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li><a href="asp ajax">ASP AJAX</a></li>
                        <li><a href="asp mvc">ASP MVC</a></li>
                    </ul>                    
                    <h5>Latest articles</h5>                 
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two columns flex-box layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242141/two-columns-flex-box-layout)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just use the layout in above mention link under your class `dropdown` if still got any issue do let me know ill post it