# How to put images (svg) beside text?

Tags: html, css, image

First of all, sorry for my bad English, hopefully, I've written this well.
I have tried many solutions on this web but I can't fix my problem.

I'm a beginner in HTML & CSS so maybe that is the reason. I'm new at this and trying to improve. I would be really grateful for your help.

What I want to do is to obtain a design like this: My first attempt worked but I can't replicate this look in other images:

[image: My first attempt, it worked but I can't replicate this look in other images]

I've tried to copy the CSS properties This is just how it's default generated (I don't know how to obtain the same design from above):

[image: This is just how it's default generated]

Here's [the HTML/CSS of the working part on codeshare](https://codeshare.io/dwlgVZ), and here's [the non-working code on codeshare](https://codeshare.io/QnLvMw).

In case the link doesn't work, here's alternative code that doesn't work:

```css
<style>
      .info2 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;        
      }
      div.info2 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 170px;
        height: 50px;
      }
        .resp2 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: roboto;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
      }
        .info3 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;        
      }
      div.info3 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 210px;
        height: 50px;
      }
      div.info3resp3 {
        display: inline-block;
      }
        .resp3 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: roboto;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
      }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="info2resp2">
    <div class="info2">
    <p>Vende/Compra tu casa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2-div"> <img class="icon2" src="/icons/icon2svg.svg" alt=""> </div>

    <div class="resp2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Donec semper purus ac erat 
    dignissim, non gravida 
    dui ullamcorper. In suscipit. &#127969 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="info3resp3">
    <div class="icon3-div"> <img class="icon3" src="/icons/icon3svg.svg" alt=""> </div> 
    <div class="info3">
    <p>Todo detallado</p>
    </div>
    <div class="resp3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
     consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Donec semper purus ac erat 
     dignissim, non gravida </p>
```

code that works:

```css
<style>
.info1 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;      
      }
      div.info1 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 170px;
        height: 50px;
  }
         .resp1 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: roboto;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
      }
      div.resp1 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px; 
        }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="info1resp1"> 
    <img class="icon1" src="/icons/icon1svg.svg" alt="">
    <div class="info1">
    <p>Perfiles Seguros</p>
    </div>
    <div class="resp1">
    <p>Asociados a un RUT verificado
    asociado a la cédula de identidad,
    puedes confiar en que estés
    hablando con una persona real y
    tendrás acceso a algunos de sus datos
    importantes. &#9989</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: use Flexbox!!! . Easy.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242141/two-columns-flex-box-layout

Answer (score 1):

i think u should learn layouting using `flex` and `grid`.

```css
.card {
  background-color: black;
  width: 240px;
  height: 270px;
  display: flex;


}

.icon1{
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.wrapper {
  
}
p{
  color: white;
}

.wrapper p:nth-child(1){
  margin: 20px 0 ;
  
}


*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding : 0 ;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="icon1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.svg" alt="">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <p>Perfiles Seguros</p>
          <p>Asociados a un RUT verificado
      asociado a la cédula de identidad,
      puedes confiar en que estés
      hablando con una persona real y
      tendrás acceso a algunos de sus datos
      importantes. &#9989</p>
  </div>
</div>
```